# Dependencies are not saving in ubuntu

Tags: reactjs, docker, dependencies, react-devtools

I am making a react js project and i am using docker. as the ubuntu restart all the dependencies start download again. i am not able to understand why dependencies not saving in the project folder. I don't want that every time my dependencies download again and again on restart.

Pull everytime on database:start in docker

latest: Pulling from library/mysql

aa18ad1a0d33: Pull complete fdb8d83dece3: Pull complete 75b6ce7b50d3: Pull complete ed1d0a3a64e4: Pull complete 8eb36a82c85b: Pull complete 41be6f1a1c40: Pull complete 0e1b414eac71: Pull complete 914c28654a91: Pull complete 587693eb988c: Pull complete b183c3585729: Pull complete 315e21657aa4: Pull complete

Digest: sha256:0dc3dacb751ef46a6647234abdec2d47400f0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker has a way to store things in cache: It checks for modifications in each lines of instruction of the Dockerfile and when it finds a difference at a line it re-runs it and all the instructions below. For the `COPY` instruction it works the same except it also checks if the files themselves have changed.
I assume that you are copying your project files **before** installing your dependencies in your Dockerfile.
You should instead copy your `package.json` first, then install the dependencies, then copy all your project's files. That way it will download new dependencies **only if your `package.json` file changed**.
Here is an example of what I mean:

```
FROM node:latest
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXEC npm run
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I think I can't understand your question. Have a nice day.

Comment: okay. but as i updated above you can check. yarn database:start pull mysql library, every time as i shutdown and start ubuntu. but i want that mysql install one time and save in the system and don't download again and again from online.